# Is there a system location for custom.css searched along with ~/.jupyter/custom/?

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

For a multiuser JupyterHub server, how do you apply customizations outside of user's home directory, so that it will affect all new users' notebooks ?

I've copied a working stylesheet from `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` to the following locations with no joy:

```
/etc/jupyter/custom
/usr/etc/jupyter/custom
/usr/local/etc/jupyter/custom
```

Answer (score 0):

The hub's job is just to spawn a docker image, so you have to change the actual image, not the hub.  The best solution I could think of is either edit your docker image, or if you're using a public image, create a docker image with that public image as the base image.  You can then add a simple COPY [/path/to/custom.jss in your host machine] [/path/to/custom.jss in your notebook].  Then if you change your notebook image to this image, it'll overwrite the custom.jss in each new notebook you create.

Comment: So, jupyterhub documentation is really confusing, or maybe the app is just so multilayered it's confusing. If you can provide a description of how to customize a spawner, i'll accept the answer. Right now, I just have `#c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'jupyterhub.spawner.LocalProcessSpawner'` in my jupyterhub_config.py, so I don't think my setup currently uses docker at all?